# selector concatenation peculiarity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across behavior that I cannot explain. I want to get an element (id='address.zipCode)' with simple selector:

```
 $('#' + prefix + 'zipCode')
```

and it doesn't work. In this case, prefix == 'address\\.'. Chrome console debugging results in:

```
> prefix
  "address\\."

> $('#' + prefix + 'zipCode')
  []
```

The most interesting part is that:

```
$('#' + "address\\." + 'zipCode')
[<input id=​"address.zipCode" name=​"address.zipCode" class=​"zipCodeMask" type=​"text" value>​]
```

Any ideas what's wrong with that?

Comment: `"address\\."` is actually the string `address\.` I think. The first backslash escapes the second one. Is the desired selector `'#address\.zipCode'`?

Comment: *"The most interesting part is that"* did you forget to finish that sentence?

Comment: How many backslashes does `prefix` *actually* have? If Chrome is anything like Firebug it looks like it has 2 backslashes? (Can you post the code where you assign `prefix`?)

Comment: Double \ is the correct way to escape `.`, and yes, it does need to be escaped.

Comment: @BrianGlaz - otherwise it will be class selector

Comment: @KevinB I believe the sentence finishes with the code snippet and result.

Comment: @KevinB Chrome displays the escaped result (eg. `> "\\."` outputs `"\."`), which means OP probably has 4 backslashes.

Comment: weird - works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/gLYL5/

Comment: @Asad as you can see, $('#' + 'address\\.' + 'zipCode') works just fine

Comment: Your code appears to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2WB6Q/

Comment: @meliniak Yes, what I'm saying is that for `> prefix` to show `"address\\."` in the Chrome REPL, the OP would have had to do `var prefix = "address\\\\."`. The OP needs one backslash in the actual string, not two, and therefore needs to type two backslashes (not four) in the string literal.

Comment: @Asad Thanks for confirming this and I think we have our answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working backwards from the behavior of the Chrome REPL (which displays the final value of the string, i.e. sans escaping characters), you actually have two backslashes in your final string. In other words, you have probably assigned `prefix` like so:

```
var prefix = "address\\\\.";
```

What you actually need is only **one** backslash, which means you should type in two backslashes in the string literal (one for escaping):

```
var prefix = "address\\.";
```